# Keyboard hides textview in webview in android

Tags: android

I have showed an textbox in a **webview** for login purpose, but when I press textbox to input characters the keyboard apperars and it hides the textbox. I also declared  **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize|adjustPan"** in manifest. But still the problem exists. Can anyone please suggest idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest check if you have

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

and if it is 3.. channge it to 4 or higher